# Objective-C strange plist to dictionary behavior

Tags: objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

i have a really simple plist which is loaded into a NSDictionary. However, when i try to access a specific value, no data is available.

This is how my plist is structured:

edit* xml got messed up. You can take a look at it at pastebin: 
http://pastebin.com/C419ZVeJ

Here i load the plist:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.plist"];
NSDictionary *metaPlistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];


NSDictionary *meta = [metaPlistData valueForKey:@"meta"];
NSDictionary *assets = [meta valueForKey:@"sd"];
```

(i have removed the line where i access the key=1 entry)

When i inspect the "meta" dictionary and the "assets" dictionary in gdb, "meta" contains the required entries. However, assets always is nil. I am really lost here.. any ideas why? I load data from plists using this approach at other locations in my code and it has never been a problem.

Comment: Your updated pastebin xml still shows the additional dictionary with just the key '1' inside...

Comment: Damn, you are right, i missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On first blush, it looks like you're off by one layer in the hierarchy. "sd" isn't a key in the "meta" dictionary, it's a key in the "1" dictionary. Try this:

```
NSDictionary *meta = [metaPlistData objectForKey:@"meta"];
NSDictionary *one = [meta objectForKey:@"1"];
NSDictionary *assets = [one objectForKey:@"sd"];
```

Note too that you should be using `-objectForKey:` for dictionary access (`-valueForKey:` will probably work in this context but it belongs to the key-value coding mechanism which is something a little different.)

(Also, not sure if this is just a paste issue, but your plist looks incomplete.)

Comment: Hi quixoto, yes the xml before was messed up. I have edited my post, and pasted the correct xml to a codepaste site. Structure should be ok now.

Comment: Checked again, still got a mistake in my markup. Your hint is correct, thanks!